# How do I apply Map[] to a function using two arguments in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In general, I was trying to compute the norm of the difference between every set two elements in a list which looks something like

```
X = {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}}
```

therefore evaluating

```
Norm[X[[1]]-X[[2]]]
Norm[X[[1]]-X[[3]]]
Norm[X[[2]]-X[[3]]]
```

Now, applying Outer[] is one possible way how to do this

```
Outer[Norm[X[[#1]] - X[[#2]]] &, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}]
```

but unfortunately it results in a quite slow code if I increase the number of elements in X and the length of each element.

Is there any possible way to construct a Map[] operation? Something like

```
MapThread[Norm[X[[#1]] - X[[#2]]] &,{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}]
```

does not work give the desired "currying" which I was looking for.
I'm using Mathematica Version 11.2.0.0, so I don't have access to Curry[].

Would be happy about any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mX = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}}
Apply[Norm@*Subtract, #] & /@ Subsets[mX, {2}]
```

Two equivalent approaches:

```
(Norm@*Subtract) @@@ Subsets[mX, {2}]
Apply[Norm@*Subtract, Subsets[mX, {2}], {1}]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to comment after so long! Thank you very much, however, I don't think that your suggestion is faster than my first suggestion...

Using `X = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1000}, {j, 100}];`:

`AbsoluteTiming[
 Outer[Norm[X[[#1]] - X[[#2]]] &, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}];]` gives `{0.00007, Null}`

Your suggestions:

`AbsoluteTiming[Apply[Norm@*Subtract, #] & /@ Subsets[X, {2}];]` gives `{1.35951, Null}`

`AbsoluteTiming[(Norm@*Subtract) @@@ Subsets[X, {2}];]` gives `{0.652799, Null}`

`AbsoluteTiming[Apply[Norm@*Subtract, Subsets[X, {2}], {1}];]`gives `0.659122, Null}`

?

Comment: These do very different things. You said you wanted *every* two elements. Your approach is only looking at 9 out of roughly 500k possible pairs of rows. Try replacing {1,2,3} with Range[1000].